# How do I enable touchscreen on my Q200E Asus laptop?

Tags: 12.04, asus, windows-8, touchscreen

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now with no luck. I'm brand new to ubuntu, and the laptop came preinstalled with Windows 8. I went and installed ubuntu 12.04 which was a pain because of the new windows 8 UEFI or whatever it is. Now I can't get the touchscreen to work on ubuntu. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does that have to do with this problem? The touch screen still works fantastically on Windows 8.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I misread your question.